# How to deploy the content of dist folder to the server root?

Tags: angular6, continuous-deployment, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to deploy all the files from dist folder to one of my folder in the server.

My bitbucket repository name is "test-project-app".

This is the script I have to deploy the application to the server.

```
script: # The script below will deploy the application to the webserver.
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install ncftp
  - ncftpput -v -u "$FTP_USERNAME" -p "$FTP_PASSWORD" -R $FTP_HOST $FTP_SITE_ROOT dist/*
```

These are my Repository variables

```
FTP_HOST: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
FTP_SITE_ROOT /public_html/test/
```

The above script automatically created folder "test-project-app" inside the test folder that contains all the files of dist folder. I want to deploy files of folder to test root.

How can I fix this?

Any help please. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had encountered the same issue before. Can you change

```
dist/*
```

into

```
dist/**/*
```

Hope this works for you.